# How to parse JSF style XHTML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, jsf, xhtml

We have a Java project which uses JSF. In our view layer we didn't use `id`s in all our XHTML files. What I want to do is to parse XHTML files and check for tags like

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{identity.username}"/>
```

The constant part is `<h:input...`>
The rest can be anything like `<h:inputSecret` `<h:inputWHATELSE` after selecting the correct tag. I want to check if there is an `id` attribute of that tag. If not, I want to add an `id` to it.

[Here](http://dpaste.com/hold/676137/) is one of our XHTML files.

I tried to do the work with Python. I tried ElementTree, piksemel and BeautifulSoup. Any help about this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: btw i did sth. without parsing xml. i did a regex search to match the corresponding pattern. in http://dpaste.com/676169/

Comment: What value do you want to assign to the id attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Beautifulsoup, you could do this as follows:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(<your_xml_here>)
nodes = soup.findAll(name=re.compile('^h:input'))
for node in nodes:
    if 'id' not in dict(node.attrs):
        node['id'] = <whatever you need>
```

As it can be seen, to get all the nodes that match the name pattern you're looking for all you need is a regular expression. After that, you can check the node attributes to make sure if `id` is defined or not and assign a new value when needed.